# Isn't rake db:rollback and rake db:migrate:redo the same?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

`rake db:rollback` and `rake db:migrate:redo` roll back to the most recent migration. Isn't it the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same. `rake db:rollback` only reverts last migration, while `db:migrate:redo` reverts last migration and then reapplies it back.